# Javascript Boolean Code

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I wrote this to switch between two states so when I click on something it will trigger this

```
var toggle=true;

if(toggle == true){
    alert('Toggle is on');
    toggle = false;
}
else{ 
    alert('Toggle is off');
    toggle = true;
}
```

It keeps alerting Toggle is on. Is there anyway I can actually 'toggle' between those two? Are there simpler ways? I am using this on a internet webpage.

Comment: When your `var toggle=true;` is inside your click event, your variable will be resetted on every click. So place the variable outside click function.

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/B9ad3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably because you put `var toggle=true;` inside the function and not before the function declaration, show us the entire function so we know what you're talking about

Comment: Yeap my fault silly mistake I included it in the function! Moved it out and its all working fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Simpler and more elegant:

```
var toggle = true;
alert(toggle ? "Toggle is on":"Toggle is off")
toggle = !toggle
```

Comment: @pythonian29033 probably not, but op also asked how to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `var toggle=true` is outside the function containing the `if(...)` code. Otherwise `toggle` will keep getting initialized to `true`.